# How to calculate the maximum value for shutdown -r +${MINUTES}?

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, shutdown

I am using CentOS 7.5.1804 with GNU bash version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

For scheduled reboots within maintenance windows I calculate the minutes from now up to the next reboot. In example, for an reboot in ~3 months I would use

```
shutdown -r +129600
```

Since interested in a better understanding of bash, I am curious about what could be the highest value and how to calculate it?

An scheduled shutdown with int32 would report

```
shutdown -r +4294967295
Shutdown scheduled for Tue 10184-07-27 ...
```

higher values are still possible, but how to calculate the possible maximum?

Comment: 8171 years is impressive uptime.

Comment: Indeed @glenn jackman, as mentioned in the question I am just curious about what could be the highest value and how to calculate it. It is to gain a better understanding about how the command and process is working and I am aware of that it is not a really rational or technically useful value. Was already looking for the source code of the command, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, /sbin/shutdown is a symlink to /sbin/systemctl.
Poking around in the systemctl source (https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/systemd/trusty), I see

- the [`shutdown_parse_argv`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/systemd/trusty/view/head:/src/systemctl/systemctl.c#L5146) function parses the time spec into a variable called `arg_when` which is of type `usec_t`
- the [`send_shutdownd`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/systemd/trusty/view/head:/src/systemctl/systemctl.c#L5734) function creates a `sd_shutdown_command` struct with that usec_t value
- the [`sd_shutdown_command`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/systemd/trusty/view/head:/src/systemd/sd-shutdown.h#L40) struct contains:

  ```
  /* Microseconds after the epoch 1970 UTC */
  uint64_t usec;
  ```

So, it appears the max time is:

```
$ \bc <<< '(2^63-1) / 10^6 / 60' # minutes
153722867280
$ \bc <<< '(2^63-1) / 10^6 / 60 / 24 / 365' # years
17548272
```

Then again, I did not read the [`parse_time_spec`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/systemd/trusty/view/head:/src/systemctl/systemctl.c#L5097) function to see how the argument is actually parsed into a time value.

Comment: Note `\bc` because I have a "bc" alias that I did not want to call here.